# loop through obj array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I have an array of objects like (below the chrome console output..)

```
[]
0: SRB {codiceSito: "I019GR", isFintoCamino: false, isFintoAlbero: false, regione: "TOSCANA"}
1: SRB {codiceSito: "I374NA", isFintoCamino: true, isFintoAlbero: false, regione: "Campania"}
2: SRB {codiceSito: "I288NA", isFintoCamino: false, isFintoAlbero: false, regione: "Campania"}
3: SRB {codiceSito: "I403NA", isFintoCamino: true, isFintoAlbero: false, regione: "CAMPANIA"}
...
```

all of those objects are created with this constructor

```
class SRB {
    constructor(codiceSito, isFintoCamino, isFintoAlbero, regione) {
        this.codiceSito = codiceSito;
        this.isFintoCamino = isFintoCamino
        this.isFintoAlbero = isFintoAlbero
        this.regione = regione
        // this.comune = comune
        // this.versioneModello = versMod
    }
}
```

and after creating each of them, I push it to an empty array `list_SRB = []`

Now, if I type in the chrome console
`list_SRB[2]` for example, I get the expected result:

`SRB {codiceSito: "I288NA", isFintoCamino: false, isFintoAlbero: false, regione: "Campania"}`

instead if I loop through it with a for loop, I get undefined...  :/

So, I would like to know how to loop through this array and get each property - value in order to "print" them on an HTML table.

every little clue is more than welcome :D

I am sorry I didn't post all the code before, please check it below:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    // SRB constructor
    class SRB {
        constructor(codiceSito, isFintoCamino, isFintoAlbero, regione) {
            this.codiceSito = codiceSito;
            this.isFintoCamino = isFintoCamino
            this.isFintoAlbero = isFintoAlbero
            this.regione = regione
            // this.comune = comune
            // this.versioneModello = versMod
        }
    }

    var files = evt.target.files

    // loop through all uploaded files (TXT-like files)
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i]
        var fileName = file.name

        if (fileName.endsWith(".ifc")) {

            list_fileNames.push(file.name)
            list_SRB_count++

            // read the IFC as txt file
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var contents = e.target.result

                // create regex searches for all data
                var regEx_codiceSito = /(codice sito',\$,IFCTEXT\('([a-zA-Z\d]{6}))/g
                var codiceSito = regEx_codiceSito.exec(contents)
                if (codiceSito) {
                    codiceSito = codiceSito[2]
                } else {
                    codiceSito = "dato non disponibile"
                } 

                var regEx_fintoCamino = /resina/gi
                var isFintoCamino = regEx_fintoCamino.exec(contents)
                if (isFintoCamino) {
                    isFintoCamino = true
                    list_SRB_fintoCamino.push(codiceSito)
                } else {
                    isFintoCamino = false
                }

                var regEx_fintoAlbero = /((IFCTEXT\('vedetaz)|(IFCTEXT\('vegetaz))/gi
                var isFintoAlbero = regEx_fintoAlbero.exec(contents)
                if (isFintoAlbero) {
                    isFintoAlbero = true
                    list_SRB_fintoAlbero.push(codiceSito)
                } else {
                    isFintoAlbero = false
                }

                var regEx_regione = /(regione',\$,IFCTEXT\('([a-zA-Z]{2,25}))/g
                var regione = regEx_regione.exec(contents)
                if (regione) {
                    regione = regione[2]
                } else {
                    regione = "dato non disponibile"
                }

                // create the SRB obj
                var thisSRB = new SRB(codiceSito, isFintoCamino, isFintoAlbero, regione)

                // push the obj to the SRB list
                list_SRB.push(thisSRB)

                // now loop through the SRB list and log the results
                for (var n = 0; n < list_SRB_count; n++) {
                    console.log(SRB) // logs correctly the entire list 
                    console.log(SRB[n]) // logs undefined
                }

            }
            reader.readAsText(file)

            countFile_Accepted++

        } else {
            countFile_NotAccepted++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us all the relevant code that you are working with, not just console output

Comment: Please, post a verifiable example.

Comment: In your code you have `SRB[n]`, not `list_SRB[n]`. Could that be your issue?

Comment: @JeremyRoman apologise. I need to sleep. I can't believe the problem was that simple :/

thank you all for your help 